# Yahoo! OAuth login screen for mobile devices

Tags: oauth, yahoo, mobile-website

This is a kind of re-post of my question on Yahoo! forums. It is just that I refer to StackOverflow more frequently...

My problem is as following: while Yahoo! OAuth http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/ is described as ready for use with mobile phones out-of-the-box it does not appear as such.

I have tried to implement sample application and use Yahoo! PHP SDK to connect with Yahoo!
Using web browser it is all nice and easy.
But while visiting Yahoo! request_auth page (http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-userauth.html) on my test mobile phone (Nokia 6300) it renders unacceptable: I am not able to see login box, cannot read information why my login would be required and all. I just see a page border and some text fragments ("Yahoo!", "Hel" (like in help...) et. al.).

Is there some parameter to force Yahoo! displaying mobile phone optimised page?
I do redirect user to this address at the moment:
https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth

BTW: if I use Opera Mini - it renders page nicely, although ommiting information about my site (which is requesting log-in).
Just that I cannot force all users to use Opera, or something.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @NickSiderakis - no, I shall admit, that I have not.
After I have migrated to new API - something slightly changed, although I am still able to reproduce this behavior, and there was no response from Yahoo! staff, as far as I am concerned.

Answer (score 4):

I've looking for a solution to this all day and eventually stumbled upon this: http://pastebin.com/8tDnrfLc

Important bit reproduced below:

```
var authPageURL = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth?oauth_token=" + oauthToken;
var yahooMobileLoginUrl = "https://login.yahoo.com/m?&.src=oauth&.lang=en-us&.intl=us&.done=" + authPageURL;
```

Basically you direct the user to the mobile auth page and give it a url to go to when it's done. That url should be the original https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth?oauth_token=... url.

Works for me!

Comment: This is actually the new OAuth 2.0 version which has a mobile  version for web login. However, OP is talking about the OAuth 1.0a which doesn't seem to have a web mobile page. OAuth 2.0 is unfortunately non-compatible with some Yahoo APIs yet (e.g. YQL).

Comment: Nvm, I just tested your technique with OAuth 1.0a and it's working, very clever! Thumbs up.

Comment: Thank you, this is a big help. Yahoo should be embarrassed that this hack is even necessary. It still is not a great user experience, because the approval page that comes next after login is not formatted properly for mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo! no doubt has a user-agent sniffing algorithm that determines what constitutes a mobile browser.  Clearly Opera Mini triggers the right behavior.  I suspect the native browser in the Nokia model you are using is not on the list, or it is emulating a desktop browser user-agent.  Unfortunately I think you have to convince Yahoo! to deem your Nokia 6300 a mobile device.

Comment: I think that OperaMini may convert page itself. There were some rendering errors using it, as far as I remember.

Comment: I've seen Facebook do this as well. :'(

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps modifying the user agent to make Yahoo! think the browser is Opera mini?

Comment: How could I make all my clients do that?
There are hundreds of thousands of them with thousands of different devices...
It shall be _Yahoo!_ call argument, I think...